# When an Azure key vault says "one or more x.509 properties are invalid", how can I debug what is wrong with my certificate?

Tags: x509certificate, azure-keyvault, x509certificate2

I am trying to generate X509 certificates in C# code (using the class **X509Certificate2**) and upload these certificates to an Azure Key Vault. When I try to upload them (programmatically or via the Azure Portal in a browser), I get the following error message:

> The specified X.509 certificate content is invalid. Error: one or more x.509 properties are invalid.

How can I debug what is wrong with my certificate generation? Is it documented what combinations of X509 properties are acceptable? If so, where can I read about it?

Output from `certutil -dump foo.pfx`:

```
> certutil -dump E:\Raven\Certificates\test2.pfx
Enter PFX password:
================ Certificate 0 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 0:
Serial Number: 86ae932f199f419115e8087f3f0cb6df747bd2adf966d46aab194f4283849635
Issuer: CN=intermediate CA
NotBefore: 24-01-2022 11:22
NotAfter: 25-01-2022 11:22
Subject: O=foo, CN=bar
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): a700464f1708cec627eabcd007ef574d1f0fc140
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
Provider = Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
Private key is NOT plain text exportable
Signature test passed
CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully.
```

[image]

Comment: Run `certutil -dump cert.pfx` to dump the file and analyze it. Make sure that the file is not PEM-encoded. PFX must be saved in binary form.

Comment: certutil output added to question text.

Comment: Open the PFX in notepad, for example and ensure that is is a binary junk (not PEM-formatted with base64 payload) and PFX file requires a password. This key cannot be imported without password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it turned out to be two things:

1. The *serial number*. I was using `RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(32)` to generate serial numbers, which was apparently bad. The vault is happier if I do `Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()`.
2. The *flags* (enum `X509KeyUsageFlags`). I tested several combinations of flags, and it turns out that whenever I use the flag `X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment` the vault will reject the certificate.

I don't know why. I suppse that if you use the `KeyEncipherment` flag, there is some other invariant that the certificate needs to obey.

In any case, when I fix the serial numbers and remove this flag, it appears that the vault accepts my certificates.

If I fix only the serial number but keep the `KeyEncipherment` flag, I get this error message:

> Unsupported key operation(s): "wrapKey", "unwrapKey". Supported values are "sign", "verify".