# Exporting certificates from AWS to Azure Key Vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-keyvault

I have been following [this sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/iot-dotnet-publisher-consumer) from AWS. I have followed the guide, downloaded the certificates, converted them into .pfx and tested them in a local code similar to the sample. The code works fine and the intended connection can be established. However, when I try to upload the certificate to Azure Key Vault, I get this error:

```
The specified X.509 certificate content is invalid. Error: one or more x.509 properties are invalid.
```

I have Googled and tested quite a few different openssl commands, and also tried to upload through PowerShell (just incase), but its always the same error. I am a bit clueless as to why this (as far as I know) *official* AWS example does not *just work*, and why I can not just export certificates from one big cloud company to another.

Does anyone have any guesses as to what is going wrong and what properties may be invalid, or how I can find out?

*PS: My Azure code is getting all configurations from the Key Vault secrets (connection strings, etc). I figured it could similarly be used to store certificates that my code can retrieve and use, instead of storing the certificate file in the project. Do let me know if I have misunderstood what kind of certificates should be saved in the Key Vault.*

Answer (score 0):

Please check if following  can be worked around:

1. Please note that Key Vault requires /accepts only a PEM or PFX file
   along with a private key.
2. If you have a private key stored separately in a different format,
   you need to combine the key with the certificate and key should not
   be encrypted. Some certificate authorities (CAs) provide certificates
   in other formats. Therefore, before you import the certificate, make
   sure that it's in either PEM or PFX file format and it uses key
   either (RSA) or elliptic-curve cryptography (ECC) encryption. see
   [***`creating a certificate with a ca not partnered with key-vault`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/certificate-scenarios#creating-a-certificate-with-a-ca-not-partnered-with-key-vault)

***Some  factors to check:***

3. Please check if the Pfx was `expired` or `Pfx password` is incorrect or
   has an invalid format.
4. Try Re-[import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-import)ing the cert from a pfx file with the `--password`
   parameter if it is password protected.
5. Also make sure you have [**`access`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/certificate-access-control) policies created create,get
   ,set,delete ,list for user that is trying to create and also for the
   application.
6. And the name of the secret  or certificate  that you are uploading
   must be `unique` and should not match with any other secret that was
   created previously. Content-type must be application/x-pkcs12 for
   pfx file.

Also check the [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70832414/when-an-azure-key-vault-says-one-or-more-x-509-properties-are-invalid-how-can) from SO reference

**References:**

1. [Understand X.509 public key certificates | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-x509-certificates) /[About Azure Key Vault Certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/about-certificates)
2. ["The parameter KeyVault Certificate has an invalid value"- Microsoft
   Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/7888/the-parameter-keyvault-certificate-has-an-invalid.html)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am gonna go through everything next week when I am back at work. I think the "CA not partnered with key-vault" part is the only thing I haven't tried yet, so I will check that out. I will give everything a new go, but I believe we have tried the rest.